# Jersey REST Client: How to add XML file to the body of POST request?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, jersey

My code so far:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("filename.xml");
Client c = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = c.resource("http://localhost:8080/api/resource");
webResource.type("application/xml");
```

I want to send contents of `filename.xml` with `POST` method but I have no idea how to add them to the body of request. I need help as in the net I was only able to find how to add `Form` args.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the java.net APIs in Java SE:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/resource");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("filename.xml");
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(fileReader);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);
transformer.transform(source, result);

os.flush();
connection.getResponseCode();
connection.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [Jersey API for `WebResource`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.7/jersey/index.html?com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html). It gives you a [`post`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.7/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#post%28java.lang.Object%29) method that accepts data.