# Making a http connection to send xml data

Tags: xml, http, blackberry, java-me

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java)
>   [Http POST in BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184223/http-post-in-blackberry)

I am trying to make a HTTP connection where i have to post some data to server the data that i have to send is a xml of the form as below

```
<userdata>
  <emailId>
  <![CDATA[xyz@gmail.com]]>
  </emailId>
  <dateTimezones>
    <dateInfo>
      <date>MAY 30,2012</date>
      <timezone>Asia/Kolkatta</timezone>
    </dateInfo>
    <dateInfo>
      <date>MAY 31,2012</date>
      <timezone>GMT</timezone>
    </dateInfo>
  </dateTimezones>
</userdata>
```

I am not aware of to send this data to server in java,i have never made a HTTP connection,i have searched but i did not got/understood to send this to server and receive the same data from server back in response.

Please explain this with an example.Here the client is blackberry device.The app has to send the data

Comment: The following may also help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6667391/383861

Comment: but this is for blackberry client

Answer (score 0):

If it is the client-methods you are looking for, try searching for [HttpClient](http://www.google.com/?q=java%20httpclient%20tutorial) on Google.

Comment: HttpClient does not work for Java-ME, which is the basis of BlackBerry's OS.

Comment: I had no idea. Anyway, I suppose the OP now has something to Google for. One good example I found: http://thewiki4opentech.org/index.php/J2ME_:_A_complete_HTTP_Client